# Django choice field populated by queryset - save id but show value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have two models, `Tag` and `TagGroup`.

```
class TagGroup(models.Model):
    tag_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag_group = models.ForeignKey(TagGroup, blank=True, null=True)
```

I've put a `TagGroup` form as a choice field into a template so that I can assign a `TagGroup` to a Tag.  I created this form to populate from a `TagGroup` queryset.

```
class TagGroupForm(ModelForm):
    tag_group_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TagGroup.objects.values_list('id', 'tag_group_name'), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TagGroup
        fields = [
            'tag_group_name'
        ]
```

I haven't seen any obvious instructions how I can assign the Id to the Tag table while showing the user only the Tag value in the choice field in the template.

Currently the above shows:

[image]

Couple of questions:

1. is the queryset correct? I have tried without "`values_list`" but it then just shows an "Object" in the form field in template?
2. how do i 'hide' the Id so i can save on it, while only showing the user the actual string value in the form field?

---

Edited to add updated form:

```
class TagGroupForm(ModelForm):
    tag_group_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TagGroup.objects.all(), to_field_name = 'tag_group_name', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TagGroup
        fields = [
            'tag_group_name'
        ]
```

this now produces the following .. looks close .. the form value has a nice string but the actual value displayed to user is still "TagGroup object".  How to get this to show?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield),

> The **str** (**unicode** on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use

So simply just assign this to the objects name and all will be ok! (Also, you don't need to use `values_list`) The reason it shows the Object by default is because this is what the default string representation is.

```
class TagGroup(models.Model):
    tag_group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_group_name

tag_group_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TagGroup.objects.all(), required=False)
```

Alternatively, if you don't wish to modify this and wish to reserve it for other uses.

> To provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override `label_from_instance`. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it

```
class TagChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
     queryset = TagGroup.objects.all()
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.tag_group_name  # or similar
```

Comment: I can buy that it is able to associate id to the selected object, so i don't need to explicitly have queryset include the id.  However, if I don't explicitly tell it which field to use as value to show user it gives "TagGroup object" in the form field as choice. If I do tell it which field to use eg values_list('tag_group_name'), then it shows the string but encoded as in my screenshot above.

Comment: @genoki - I'm not sure if you've seen my initial answer or my completely revised one, but the text it chooses to display is based on the string representation of the model, you can then choose to provide a different *value* by using `to_field_name` if you wish, but since you were asking to still use the id as the value you just need to set the correct display text

Comment: thank you. I did also try with the `to_field_name` which didn't return desired results. I updated my question with its results.  Btw what do you mean by _string representation of the model_ ?

Comment: @genoki - I've updated my first example, I'm pretty sure this is what you want

Comment: Ok I see now. By _string representation of the model_ you meant what the TagGroup `def __str__(self):` defines as the string to return when this model is called. I had not defined that before.  The subclass you provided is an alternative to hardcoding the model's string to return. So one must do one of these things in order to make a queryset choice field to work.